# Implement Dependency injection in MVC (Webservices)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection

In my project, Iám calling my Code Repository from MVC Controllers.
My Repository  have function to work with Exchange Server, Echange Managed API.

Now, i want to implement dependency injection in my project.

I can not figure out what in my code must be modified to call Repository with dependency injection

Can anybody help ?

Her my Repository:

```
  public class ExchangeEws : IExchangeEws
{
                public List<DateTime> GetAvaliableBookingDays(ExchangeService service, List<Advisor> advisors, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int Num_Appt)
            {

                List<DateTime> avaliableBookingDays = new List<DateTime>();


                foreach (Advisor adObj in advisors)
                {
                    // Get user's calendar folder 
                    CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, adObj.EmailAddress), new PropertySet());

                    //  appointments to retrieve.(CalendarView return recurring appointment)
                    CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, Num_Appt);

                    //  def properties to get returned
                    cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.IsRecurring, AppointmentSchema.LegacyFreeBusyStatus, AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.AppointmentType);


                    FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);

                    if (appointments.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        avaliableBookingDays.AddRange((from appObj in appointments
                                                       where (appObj.AppointmentType == AppointmentType.Occurrence || appObj.AppointmentType == AppointmentType.Exception) && appObj.LegacyFreeBusyStatus == LegacyFreeBusyStatus.Free && appObj.Subject.ToLower().Contains("kwodkowdkowdow")
                                                       select appObj.Start).ToList());
                    }
                }


                List<DateTime> distinctDates = avaliableBookingDays
                                               .GroupBy(day => day.Date)
                                               .Select(g => g.First())
                                               .ToList();

                return distinctDates;
            }
    }
```

Here my Controller:

```
         public class HomeController : Controller
        {        
          public ActionResult service()
            {
 List<Advisor> adv = new List<Advisor>() { new Advisor { ID = 1, Location = "London", EmailAddress = "dwded@dd.dk", Name = "Loppe" } };

                ExchangeService service= ExchangeEws.GetExchangeConnection("xxxx@jj.com", password);

                ExchangeEws x = new ExchangeEws();



                 x.GetAvaliableBookingDays(service, adv, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(45), 20);


                return View();
            }
```